# Smarty: Implode an array and assign it to a var

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, implode

**I want to archieve the following:**

"I am a descriptive sentence"

**I put it in an array (for creating keywords for meta tags) via:**

```
[{assign var='meta_key_arr' value=' '|explode:$oEntry->FCLONGDESC_1}]
```

That works so far. My result is an array like that:

```
array([I],[am],[a],[descriptive],[sentence])
```

The goal is to get a String like that "I,am,a,descriptive,sentence"

I wanted to implode the array seperated by a comma:
    [{', '|implode:$meta_key_arr}]

This works fine, but I want to assign the values to another variable $meta_key. Which does not work. I read the manual but the only thing I could find was the syntax above.

```
[{assign var='meta_key' value=' '|', '|implode:$meta_key_arr}]
```

did not work. And this didn't work either.

```
[{assign var='meta_key' value=' ' ', '|implode:$meta_key_arr}]
```

How can I use the implode function correct? There is a much easier way for sure.

Comment: Much easier way is to process data in a controller.

Comment: @u_mulder I am very new to smarty. Actually I do try and error. But I know PHP though.

Comment: Smarty is a template engine. It means it just __outputs__ data. That's why you should prepare your data in a controller

Comment: @u_mulder I do understand your point, but it doesn't help me to solve my current very small problem. I just want to split a sentence to create some keywords for meta keywords.

Comment: Open ypur controller and create a variable __there__

Comment: ok, to be clear. I am working on a template of an OXID plugin. No need to edit a controller. I am pretty sure, it's way more simpler. I just need to know how to chain the implode to my assign statement.

Comment: Just `', '|implode:$meta_key_arr`?

Comment: my problem was not the implode. It was the assignment of the result to a var. But I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:**

```
[{foreach from=$meta_key_arr item=mkey}]
   [{assign var='meta_key' value=', '|implode:$meta_key_arr}]
[{/foreach}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the original string and replace spaces with commas?

```
[{assign var='meta_key' value=$oEntry->FCLONGDESC_1|replace:' ':', '}]
```